# Why I'm getting time-out on each four call of the HttpWebResponse.GetResponse method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebresponse

Why I'm getting time-out on each four call of the HttpWebResponse.GetResponse method? And it doesn't matter how often I call it. I tried to call it each 30 seconds, 2 minutes - no difference - always get timeout on the fourth call.

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 15000;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse resp = e.Response)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)resp).StatusCode + ((HttpWebResponse)resp).StatusDescription);

            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: (i) WebException.Response is not guaranteed to non-null, so you should guard for that. (ii) so you have a response... you should get its response stream and read it to the end, then dispose of it, then dispose of the response itself (something you only do in the exception case above)

Comment: Thanks, adding response.Dispose(); after I read the response done the trick.

Comment: So this is what `using` statements are for. Also, if you have a response, you should always read the response stream to the end in every case. The data is headed your way anyway.